# What's the simplest way to create a beanplot in MATLAB?

Tags: data-visualization, matlab

What is the simplest script for generating a beanplot (see [article](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v28/c01/paper) published in the *Journal of Statistical Software*) in MATLAB?

Comment: [Mathworks](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/searchresults/?c[]=entiresite&q=beanplot) seems not to have an entry for `beanplot` or `bean plot`. This is not a good sign.

Comment: This kind of plot takes a few seconds to make in R, after you've imported your data. Is it important that it's in matlab?

Comment: a combination of `ksdensity` and `fill` should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an excellent series of plot tools on Matlab File Exchange that creates bean plots among several other distribution plots.

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23661-violin-plots-for-plotting-multiple-distributions-distributionplot-m

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't necessarily what you are looking for, but I suggested to the "improvement request" folks at my work that they ask for variation on the bean plot as option for variability plots in one of MATLAB's competitors.  We are a relatively big customer so a useful proportion of our requests actually do get implemented in the product.  It sometimes takes a year or three before it is rolled out.

I see the bean plot as having good value for EDA in my work environment.  If their competitors have it and their competitors customers are using it for good value then there is incentive for MathWorks to implement it in MATLAB.  Eventually there is good incentive, it takes time.

That is how to make it happen natively inside MATLAB.  That is not how to hack it to work with existing MATLAB methods.

Comment: @Nick Cox - for five decades it was "MatLab", short for Matrix Laboratory.  It was the successful wrapping of two Fortran Libraries (linpack, eispack?) into a new and marketable product.  The change to "MATLAB" is relatively recent, and likely to be relatively short-lived compared to half a century.  It is a branding change and the market is always in motion.

Comment: The proprietary and registered name is still MATLAB. The website www.mathworks.com uses that name and I see it in the company's documentation. It's clear that the origin is as you describe, as a confection based on two words, and it's most unlikely that an all-caps name would be introduced now. Also, many writers now write Matlab (which I see much more commonly than MatLab, FWIW). But no matter: The principle for CV, I suggest, is that the proprietary names are those most to be respected.

Comment: (Oddly, I am more usually editing the bizarre misspelling STATA, a name not used by its company for 30 years, back to the standard spelling Stata.)

Comment: @NickCox - If we have to go back and edit the content every time the name chances, then in my personal opinion, that introduces more work than it solves.  The purpose of language is to communicate ideas.  In this case, with or without capitalization, the intended audience understood the idea with minimal overhead and thus it achieved its purpose.

Comment: I agree broadly with your opening statement, but in this case I think the company has used exactly the same name for decades: the prevalence of mutant versions needs another explanation. You're free to regard my edit as trivial or unnecessary just as I am free to prefer a correct name to a slightly incorrect one. I agree strongly that your intended meaning was entirely clear. Intended meanings are often clear but that doesn't rule out edits to clean up small glitches, which is what many of us do.

Comment: I read http://uk.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/the-origins-of-matlab.html as implying that the name MATLAB has been in use for many years.